# Drag only when not a Swipe

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, swipe, drag

I have UIView that I want the user to be able to drag around the screen.  However, there is also a specific action I want to occur if the swipe up in the same UIView.  Right now, I have a Swipe Up Gesture recognizer attached to the UIView and I have the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded methods implemented.  It all works fine except for one issue, when the User Swipes Up, the UIView first goes up a little, then the Gesture Recognizer takes over and completes the Swipe Up action.  Is there a way that I can delay the drag for just a split second until the Gesture Recognizer for the Swipe Up fails, then the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded take over and operate as usually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the touches* methods and replace them with a pan gesture recognizer. Then you can require that the swipe gesture fails before the pan gesture acts.  You can implement the behavior like this:

[self.panRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.swipeRecognizer];

as suggested by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html

*edit* as an alternative you can modify the touchesMoved so that it will only move your view if the status of your swipe recognizer is "UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed", which will give you the same behavior but without requiring you to modify too much code.

Comment: I ended up adding a panRecognizer to the view and had it ignore all up/down gestures, which then fell to the next responder and they could be interpreted as usual.  The panRecognizer then dealt with all right/left gestures as it should.